# WebLogic 12c console runs extremely slow after adding many managed servers

Tags: weblogic12c

I'm building a Web application running on App Server Oracle Weblogic 12c (WLS). On WLS, I have 1 Admin server and some Manager Server. When I increase the number of Manager Server (more than 20 physical machines), the Administration Console and Enterprise Manager of Admin Server running extremely slow or inaccessible.

```
Hardware configuration of each server:
CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2660v3- 20 cores 
RAM: 32 G
HDD: 320G
```

How do I find the root cause and how to fix this? Which tool I should use to identify the problem ? Please give me some advices. Thanks

Comment: I am assuming that you are using just 1 single OS install for all of these servers (Admin + 20 Managed). In that case, it probably is due to competing resources. Use JVisualVM to start your investigation.

Comment: No, I deployed on 21 servers (physical machines)

Comment: Action Plan: Shut down all servers. Start Admin Server. Attach JVisualVM to Admin Server. Start Managed Servers one by one and observe JVisualVM for signs of JVM or Thread overload.

Comment: Do I have to check any log of WLS?

Comment: [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) is an GUI tool for JVM monitoring and profiling. It does not write to WLS logs.

Comment: No, I mean any log files produced by WLS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142153/discussion-between-vivekratansinha-and-barcelona).

Answer (score 2):

Using this for AdminServer and Managed Servers solved the issue for us (WebLogic 12.2.1.2).

```
-Dweblogic.UseEnhancedIncrementAdvisor=false
```

Linux/Unix: Simply add the folowing to $DOMAIN_HOME/bin/setUserOverrides.sh .

```
export JAVA_OPTIONS=" ${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.UseEnhancedIncrementAdvisor=false "
```

Windows (Not validated): Simply add the folowing to %DOMAIN_HOME%/bin/setUserOverrides.cmd .

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=" %JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dweblogic.UseEnhancedIncrementAdvisor=false "
```

You can create the file if it does not exists, it will overrides settings when usings startWebLogic or startManagedWebLogic.

Hope it helps